# object coordinates using microsoft cognitive services computer vision API

Tags: computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

Cognitive Services computer vision API , Analyze image returns different objects in the image and confidence level. I want to find coordinates of these objects in the image. basically coordinates of boundary box of identified object.

Regards,
Bharat

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not yet available for Computer Vision.  This is currently an active idea on their feedback forum at https://cognitive.uservoice.com/

[Returns location of objects on the image (people, tree, car's, etc.)](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/430309-computer-vision/suggestions/15379455-returns-location-of-objects-on-the-image-people)